How would a monster be part of a planet's core?
Okay so I know this absolutely isn't possible but what is the most likely way this would be possible? This idea is also very much still in progress but I think asking this would help. I'm thinking of having a creature as part of a planet's core and when it leaves the core, the planet begins collapsing or something until the creature returns where there's damage but everyone on the planet survives. I'm thinking of just having open space around the core to give space for the monster but is that even possible? Or should it live in liquid instead? And additionally, why would it be an essential part of the core logically? And what would the biology of the monster have to be like in order to live off the core? An answer to any of these questions would help greatly, thanks, I know these probably don't make the most sense but hopefully someone can find some logic in here.

Sounds like a great take on a classic fantasy idea that doesnt necessarily need any science backing it up. If you are sure you need or want physics related reasoning, please pick just one question you'd like to ask about your planet monster and its habitat. It's fine to post additional questions later.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The Demon Lord's answer fits with the advice given here: Feasibility of lava beings?

In his house at R'lyeh dead Cthulhu waits dreaming
Who says the Monster has to be one of Flesh and Blood that conforms to the physical laws of this universe?
The notion of Ancient, timeless entities that exist outside of our understanding living in hidden places, whilst a bit of a Trope, is a damn good one and always lots of fun.
So my answer is: Don't worry about the details - just simply state there is such a creature at the centre of the world - and be done with it.
The more you try and explain or justify it, the less mystery there will be - and said mystery makes for a cracking good story.

If you stay "a bit of a trope" since before 800 BC, you get a promotion to timeless mythic archetype!

okay after some consideration, i am thinking too much on this topic. it’s time for my story to stop being so compliant with science, mysterious core creature it is

Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn! Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn!
